# How to extend a base template to other templates

Tags: go, go-templates

How do I extend a base html file, such as:

base.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>My Site</title>
    </head>
    <body>
   <!-- insert html here -->
    </body>
    </html>
```

And then create a page that inherits that base template, in Python Jinja2 I would do:

main.html

```
{{ extend "base.html" }}
```

main.html now has all the HTML from base.html. Then so long as I defined an area in my base.html file to insert html into I could do it from main.html, in Jinja2 it would look like:

base.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>My Site</title>
    </head>
    <body>
   {{ block "body" }}

   {{ endblock }}
    </body>
    </html>
```

then in main.html

```
{{ extend "base.html" }}
{{ block "body" }}
<h1>Title</h1>
{{ endblock }}
```

I can't figure the way to do that in any of the Go frameworks. They all seem to say to 'define' a template and then insert HTML "components" into it, I want to go the other way and define a base HTML file and inherit it into my other HTML files to build upon, if that makes sense?

Comment: Do not try to emulate other language features in go. You have to change your design. Split your base HTML to a header and footer template, and include those in your pages.

Comment: Hmm that might be my issue, I'm stuck in a different mindset of design.

Comment: @Ari you mean something like this? https://play.golang.com/p/CIu7fj1hCTn

Comment: @mkopriva exactly! I think thats it. Is there a way to perform this within a template? Or does it have to be done server side?

Comment: @Ari perform what exactly within the template? I'm confused. Also the question about server side is confusing. Can you be more specific and explain *what exactly* you want to do, *where* you want to do it, and *with what* you want to do it?

Comment: Templates, typically, _are_ server side. So I'm also confused what you mean.

Comment: Sorry I've figured it out finally, I've moved away from Go frameworks and I'm using the built in packages, behaving as I was expecting/used to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use these templates.

base.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>My Site</title>
</head>
<body>
{{block "body" $}}{{end}}
</body>
</html>`
```

main.html:

```
{{define "body"}}<h1>Title</h1>{{end}}
```

Parse the templates in order of extension using the standard library template package;

```
t := template.Must(template.ParseFiles(
     "base.html", 
     "main.html"))
```

Execute the resulting template.

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/H3x9anzz0Eo)